Jenkins Kubernetes Cloud Configuration
Recently I have been configuring a Jenkins to use a Kubernetes cloud to deploy pods like workers/slaves but I'm having problems to achieve this.

I'm trying this scenario.
But I configure this and doesn't works properly. I got a 504 error from nginx:

from nginx controller pod I got this log:
2024/05/05 18:04:45 [error] 7804#7804: *166176182 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) 
while reading response header from upstream, 
client: 10.0.0.134, 
server: jenkinstest.somedomain.com, 
request: "POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection HTTP/2.0", 
upstream: "http://10.0.4.86:8080/manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection", 
host: "jenkinstest.somedomain.com", 
referrer: "https://jenkinstest.somedomain.com/manage/cloud/kubernetes/configure"

10.0.0.134 - - [05/May/2024:18:04:45 +0000] 
"POST /manage/descriptorByName/org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud/testConnection HTTP/2.0" 504 562 
"https://jenkinstest.somedomain.com/manage/cloud/kubernetes/configure" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 
549 300.001 [jenkins-jenkins-8080] [] 
10.0.4.86:8080 0 300.000 504 3be2167acb862a9cc9a5c8be5fce9a7f

Do I need any extra configuration? I configured the proxy properly and other applications work correctly.
Thanks.

I solved the problem, I configure a proxy in JAVA_OPT for jenkins I deleted it and it works.

